# Set attribute for a taglib through javascript

Tags: javascript, grails, attributes, taglib

I have a case where I want to set a attribute of a taglib, on the item selected from the drop down menu.

So how do I do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taglib prepares html on server side, makes a static string, a html, that will be sent to browser. Javascript is working on client side, in browser, against prepared html document.

You can update model of current document (HTML DOM), but there is no way to make changes against logic that already had finished, generated a html and you've received result. If you're looking for a fast and easy tool for manipulating HTML DOM, then take a look at [jQuery](http://jquery.com)

Or you can also make ajax calls to server, render a html on server side (using any taglib), and respond with updated html. Take a look at [remoteFunction](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/remoteFunction.html), [remoteLink](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/remoteLink.html), etc

Answer (score 0):

Use attributes.

```
def doSomething = { attrs, body ->
    def pid = attrs?.param;
    out << 'You gave the following param'+ pid
}
```